# open dir failed. Value too large for defined data type

Tags: c, opendir, uclibc

I have tried all the existing solutions in stack overflow for similar questions :
Mostly it was suggested to declare `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` to `64`. But this did not work.

Sample Code :

```
dir = opendir("/data/system/dropbox");
if (!dir) {
    PRINT_ERROR("open dir - %s failed. %s\n",
            "dropbox", strerror(errno));
    return -errno;
}
```

The following is the error(`strerror(errno)`) I get when I try to open a directory (`/data/system/dropbox`). I am using `uClibc`

```
>> Value too large for defined data type
```

Comment: Does this help? http://schematik.blogspot.se/2010/03/enable-large-file-support-in-uclibc.html

Comment: "*when I try to open a directory*" using which (system-)call/function?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Sorry for not posting code. I missed it. Updated now.

Comment: @alk opendir call. I update the q. Please have a look again.

Comment: @alk I just checked. It is enabled. grep -irn "UCLIBC_HAS_LFS=y" *
---> include/config/auto.conf:20:UCLIBC_HAS_LFS=y
uClibc.conf:88:UCLIBC_HAS_LFS=y

Comment: does your code have #include <sys/types.h> and #include <dirent.h> followed by DIR * dir = NULL; before the code you displayed?

Answer (score 1):

If this happens to be on a big-endian machine, you might want to make sure you're using the latest version of uClibc.  Your symptoms sound like [this bug](http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/commit/?id=fb3d0e177f40e9cbb54827d565e778eda2c5a58d) which was fixed last year.

Comment: I could not see the exact path of the fix in my uclibc. But taking the latest uclibc worked for me. I am now trying to get the patch that did the work for me